# GTM Strips URL fragments breaking functionality

Tags: google-tag-manager, url-fragment

We have on our site a physician directory search which has been working cross platform for years. Over the last few months, we have been getting reports that the functionality is broken. My debugging into this issue has led me to find that GTM is actually stripping the URL fragments breaking the functionality in all browsers but IE.

We use Ajax calls to retrieve the directory page by page, 10 items at a time. Some results can yield up to 15 pages, but users are no longer able to get past page 2 of the result set. After page 2 it produces the search page again.

This was rewritten a number of years ago to utilize the URL hash as opposed to using the original cookie based system which simply didn't work. This can be easily reproduced using Chrome by:

1. Visit https://www.montefiore.org/doctors
2. Click Search By Specialty
3. Click Family Practice
4. Navigate to any secondary page, you will see that the hash fragments have been striped
5. When you try to navigate to any tertiary page, you are simply presented with the specialty list again.

I have gone through various debugging sessions and have even outsourced the issue to our outside developers, but the issue remains unresolved. Any idea on what could be causing GTM to strip out the fragments?

Comment: I don't think I'm able to recreate the issue in Chrome, unless I'm navigating wrong. The fragment is removed on the doctor detail page but I can still navigate back and see the correct fragment. Either way, nothing in GTM should be modifying or removing the fragment unless you've specifically written the JS to do so. Without seeing the content of your container this one may be a tough one to dig into. Maybe you can provide a bit more info around if this is a cross browser issue, how you were able to determine the issue is GTM-specific, and what custom HTML tags you're running in there.

Comment: Navigating to subsequent pages is when the issue appears. You can move from the first page into a detail page and return with no issue, but when you try to move to subsequent pages, the issue becomes obvious.

Comment: I discovered the source of the issue by painstakingly stepping through the code. This is where I found that GTM was updating the URL fragments and ended up clearing them.

When I say navigating to subsequent pages, I mean subsequent result pages. Move to results page 2 then results page 3 and you will be returned to the specialty selection page again and the fragments are gone.

This has been working fine in all browsers for the past 7 years and stated showing this issue in July in all browsers but IE.